# implementing Geocoder

Tags: android, android-context

I'm trying to implement `Geocoder` in a class that implements `Runnable` and I get error at this line:

```
Geocoder myLocation = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
```

I don't think Android likes `this`.

But what context should I pass in for this to work?

```
public class ClientThread_special implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        Geocoder myLocation = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    } 

}
```

I'm trying to implement the `Geocoder` in a class that doesn't extend `Activity` and I have problems in passing the context for the `Geocoder` constructor.

Android doesn't like `this` for my class. I also tried with `getApplicationContext`...but still it says that "it can't be resolved..".

Comment: Ok embry, Context is a class, which you need an instance of (like an activity, or application context). "this" is a Runnable. Using just the name of a class won't work. This seems to be more of a question of java syntax and semantics than android

Answer (score 2):

You must pass Context instance somehow. Without it Geocoder won't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you need Context instance and don't need an activity,extend the class  ClientThread_special  with Service and I think you wont need Runnable then.